# (Swift) tableView application iOS fails because of "Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type"

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am trying to create a database-based application for iOS and I am, more or less, forced to use Xcode 6.2 Beta 3, because I started the project with 6.2 and run iOS 8.2 on my testdevice. I have by the way figured out that the beta forces me to use the standard keypad, instead of decimal pad, otherwise the app stops working.

I can´t figure out what is wrong. And when I try to comment the function out something is still wrong in this file. Are there any missing connections between the VC-swift-file, tableVC-swift-file and datamodel-file?
I changed the name of the entity list once, and then changed back, because of another error I had before. But after I did it seems like the debug area doesnt catch the data I try to save to the database either...

The error says "Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type"

Here is the code that is marked red on the initial line:

```
  if let ip = indexPath {
        var data: NSManagedObject = tankningslista[ip.row] as NSManagedObject
    cell.textLabel?.text = data.valueForKey("datum") as String

    }
```

The whole function looks like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // Configure the cell...
    let CellID: NSString = "Cell"

    var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellID) as UITableViewCell

if let ip = indexPath {
        var data: NSManagedObject = tankningslista[ip.row] as NSManagedObject
    cell.textLabel?.text = data.valueForKey("datum") as String

    }


    return cell
}
```

I have followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ymz6i07DRM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way without using condition:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

// Configure the cell...
let CellID: NSString = "Cell"

var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellID) as UITableViewCell
var data: NSManagedObject = tankningslista[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject
cell.textLabel.text = data.valueForKey("datum") as? String

return cell
}
```

Comment: The indexPath argument has been changed from `NSIndexPath!` to `NSIndexPath` as part of the general cleanup of optionals in mappings from Obj-C to Swift.